# Concat using two different tables

Tags: mysql

How do I concat the two columns (wmsmatch.barcode & outerb.checkd) from two different tables based on this code:

```
select * from wmsmatch join outerb on wmsmatch.id = outerb.id
```

`

```
Table: wmsmatch
Columns:
id int(10) 
barcode varchar(100)

Table: outerb
Columns:
Product_Code varchar(100) 
Brand varchar(100) 
Product varchar(100) 
Size varchar(100) 
Barcode varchar(100) 
Checkd varchar(100) 
id int(11) AI PK
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONCAT(wmsmatch.barcode , outerb.checkd) as concat_field, *
from wmsmatch 
join outerb on wmsmatch.id = outerb.id
```

Comment: error code 1064, select word is underlined with red

Comment: Try using `wmsmatch.*` instead off `*` @Eduards

Comment: unknown table 'wsmatch' im just looking into some examples on google, ill get back and see what  i got

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(wmsmatch.barcode, outerb.checkd) 
  FROM wmsmatch, outerb WHERE wmsmatch.id = outerb.id;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(wmsmatch.barcode, outerb.checkd) 
FROM wmsmatch, outerb WHERE wmsmatch.id = outerb.id;
```

Comment: try to avoid the old ansi comma join syntax it's from SQL 86/89 standards i believe.. Use the JOIN syntax which you used in the question.

Comment: how would this be recoded? `SELECT CONCAT(wmsmatch.barcode, outerb.checkd) 
FROM wmsmatch join outerb on wmsmatch.id = outerb.id;` like this?

Comment: @Eduards yes, `,` becomes `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`